# TrueZip creates virtual directory instead of archive

Tags: java, zip, archiving, java-6, truezip

I'm having an issue with the following code:

```
    TFile src = new TFile(this.getMellomStasjon());
    TFile dst = new TFile(this.getZipFolder()+""+zipFile+".zip");
    if(dst.isDirectory())
        dst = new TFile(dst, src.getName());

    TFile.cp_rp(src, dst, null);
    TFile file = newNonArchiveFile(dst);
    if(dst.isArchive())
        TFile.umount(dst);
```

My goal is to put a directory containing files into a ZIP-archive using TrueZip. The problem is that the code works locally but not on the production computer. Locally I get a single ZIP-file, but in production I get a folder containing the files I'm trying to put in the archive (virtual directory). I have to use TrueZip because I'm archiving content over 4GB.

Is there any way to force TrueZip to create an archive instead of a (virtual) directory?

Comment: Are you certain it's not? Some operating systems *present* zip files as virtual directories, at least optionally.

Comment: Before I switched to TrueZip I used the default libraries in Java, ZipOutputStream, and created entries. When using that library all the ZIP archives appeared as regular files, not directories as now when using TrueZip.

Comment: I am also trying to create a zip archive file but end up creating a directory. I am trying it out on Windows (NTFS) OS. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It probably didn't work because the JAR artifact of the module TrueZIP Driver ZIP was not present on the run time class path.

To make sure it is, you could make the ZipDriver a compile time dependency by setting a custom TArchiveDetector. Here is an example: http://truezip.java.net/usecases/aff.html

The code you show here is problematic. You should probably fix it to:

```
// Call this once at application startup to make the ZipDriver a compile time
// dependency.
TFile.setDefaultArchiveDetector(
  new TArchiveDetector(
  "zip",
  new ZipDriver(IOPoolLocator.SINGLETON)));

// Here's the work.
TFile src = new TFile(this.getMellomStasjon());
TFile dst = new TFile(this.getZipFolder(), zipFile + ".zip");
TFile.cp_rp(src, dst, TArchiveDetector.NULL);
TFile.umount(dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative library by Apache, [Commons Compression](http://commons.apache.org/compress/). Using it instead of TrueZip. Seems to support >4gb files as well.